# Flask and Ldap3 not playing nicely together

Tags: python, flask, ldap3

I'm building an internal app for my company, and are looking into using ldap3 to connect to our exchange server to validate login credentials.

I am integrating into a flask app and have a login view with the following code

```
@authBP.route('login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def loginView():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        server = Server(current_app.config['LDAP_SERVER'], get_info=ALL)

        connection = Connection(server,
                                user='domain\{initials}'.format(initials=form.init.data),
                                password=form.passwd.data,
                                auto_bind=True)

        if not connection.bind():
            flash('not authenticated')
        else:
            flash('authenticated')

        return redirect(url_for('indexBP.indexView'))  
       
    return render_template('auth/login.html', form=form)
```

The above code works fine when I login using my actual credentials, but when I try to login using wrong credentials I do not get a flash message, but in stead get an error 500 page and the following terminal error:

> raise LDAPBindError(error) ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPBindError:
> automatic bind not successful - invalidCredentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `auto_bind=True`, a `LDAPBindError` will be raised if credentials are wrong. I can see two solutions (the first one seems more pythonic to me):

```
# 1st one with try/except
    try:
        Connection(server, user='user', password='****', auto_bind=True)
        flash('authenticated')
    except LDAPBindError:
        flash('not authenticated')

# 2d one with if and without auto_bind

    conn = Connection(server, user='user', password='****')
    if conn.bind():
        flash('authenticated')
    else:
        flash('not authenticated')
```